# What is the most suitable IPC between programs in C

Tags: c, windows

I've been building 2 programs in C. The first program is a service that automatically shutdowns the pc if the time is past 22:00 with a countdown of 1 minutes. And at the same time it opens the second program and ask for username and password via ShellExecution in winapi. If the login is successful in the second program then the shutdown is totaly canceled. Then when the second program is closed or terminated then the shutdown process repeats all over again if the time is still past 22:00. My problem is how should I allow or make this kind of communication to happen between the two program. I'm thinking of using shared memory or pipe. I'm not sure what kind of ipc is suitable for this kind of situation. Note that if the second program is already open and logged in the shutdown process would not occure. And it should have no problem even if multiple instances of the second program is open and logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you need another process.   I'd be tempted to do the login/password with another thread.   That gives you shared memory with little effort.

Not being a crack Windows programmer, I don't know if you can do the ShellExecution in another thread, or if protections will get in your way.

If it didn't work and you had to do another process, I'd try a UNIX style pipe but those don't exist on Windoes, you get to a named pipes.   Pipe are usually better than shared memory for security and complexity reasons.   A trick is to make sure that only the correct program is on the other end of the pipe. That may or may not matter depending on how clever you expect an attacker to be.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a good way to eliminate ipc all together. But then I wouldn't be able to modify the database on the go without launching new instance of the service? Because my second program has the capabilities to change specified range of time also in my database

Comment: Then use named pipes and think about the security requirements.